# Angular OpenID Code flow with PKCE implementation

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2, oidc-client-js

I'm start learning and implementing an authorization / authentication on my simple SPA using Angular 8 as my client web app. I use the `oidc-client-js` library for my client and `identityserver4` for my STS. I'm following the sample provided of [oidc-client-js on github](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/dev/samples/Angular). In the said example, it uses `Implicit` flow but, upon reading to other blogs and forums, they encouraging you to use `code` flow with `Pkce` instead, which I'm trying to implement now. Below are my implementation codes.

**auth-service.ts**
[image]

**redirect html**
[image]

**stub client**
[image]

Now, my problem is that, when I click the `Login` link on my client web app, I'm receiving the below error.

[image]

But, when I reverted it to `Implicit` flow, I can successfully login to my web app without any issue.

Can someone guide me on how do I implement the `code` flow with `Pkce`?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Auth Code flow, you need to add this to your Oidc client config on your callback page.

```
response_mode: "query"
```

I figured it out by looking at the comment from Brock on this issue: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/780

Answer (score 0):

I have some code + write ups that I think will help you, though they aren't Angular and you'll need to translate. You can run the code for my sample SPA via the steps on this page - maybe also see the iblog's Index page for write ups on the initial SPA code sample: https://authguidance.com/2019/04/07/final-spa-overview. Happy to answer any follow on questions ..